# How to get two separate callbacks from single pin in C on Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: c, raspberry-pi-pico

I need to detect falling and rising edge of signal and call separate callbacks for such events.

I tried that like this, but looks like this is not working. :

```
 gpio_set_irq_enabled_with_callback(2, GPIO_IRQ_EDGE_RISE, true, &ThisIsCallBack1);
 gpio_set_irq_enabled_with_callback(2, GPIO_IRQ_EDGE_FALL, true, &ThisIsCallBack2);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details in which way it is not working.

Comment: And, please, explain what you want to achieve with separate callbacks. (In case the GPIO is connected to a switch/button, you will need debouncing.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation of `gpio_set_irq_enabled_with_callback`](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__gpio.html#ga6165f07f4b619dd08ea6dc97d069e78a) you can only define one callback this way.

> All GPIOs/events added in this way on the same core share the same callback; for multiple independent handlers for different GPIOs you should use `gpio_add_raw_irq_handler` and related functions.

> This method is equivalent to:
> `gpio_set_irq_enabled(gpio, event_mask, enabled);`
> `gpio_set_irq_callback(callback);`
> `if (enabled) irq_set_enabled(IO_IRQ_BANK0, true);`

The [documentation of `gpio_add_raw_irq_handler`](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__hardware__gpio.html#ga2e78fcd487a3a2e173322c6502fe9419) states

> Multiple raw handlers should not be added for the same GPIO, and this method will assert if you attempt to.

So using this lower level function does not help either.

I'm not absolutely sure about the following:
A single GPIO can have only one event mask which edge(s) shall trigger an interrupt. It is not possible to add different ISRs for different edges.
To distinguish different edges you would need to check which event occurred in your ISR or callback function. I guess this is not a feature of the default ISR or callback function, so you will have to implement this distinction yourself.